# automatic user login by reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, authentication, form-authentication

Given is an application behind a Nginx configured as reverse proxy. The application requires user login via a web form and HTTP POST. Is there a possibility to provide the credentials of a generic technical user to Nginx and let it automatically do a login, so that users don't have to login explicitly anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be tough without some kind of module :) but If it is an internal application you might tell nginx to to add certain headers to every request and authenticate by them. But if it is a production app I wouldn't go this path :)

Comment: Any hints you would give to someone considering writing such a module?

Comment: Only things you can Google youreself: http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html and http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules or you can write simple html page (simple form and onload submit) that will be returned to users and automaticly log them and then in ngnix i think you could redirect them to your app :) That's just a guess